# Put multiple fields in one index

Tags: mongodb

When I have a collection of users, with a structure like this:

```
{
    ...
    phone:"XXXXXXXXXX",
    email:"XXXXXXXXXX",
    ...
 }
```

Is there a way to put both the fields `phone` and `email` into one index, for example called `contactinfos`, so that I can query my user by their phonenumber OR by their email address like this:

```
db.users.find({contactinfos:"E-Mail-Address or Phonenumber"})
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create an aggregate field. You can query your collection with [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator:

```
db.users.find( { $or: [ { email: "email@somethingc.com"}, { phone: "123456" } ] } );
```

This will find all documents with either e-mail OR phone.

You can then create a [compound index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/) on both fields to make the query faster (if you're using MongoDB 2.4).

If you're using MongoDB 2.6 you can take advantage of [index intersection](http://blog.mongohq.com/at-the-mongodb-2-6-index-intersection/) and create two separate indexes for those fields.

Comment: Will mongodb 2.6 automatically do the intersection of the in the query you mentioned? Or would I have to modify the query to enable the intersection?

Comment: If you create index on `email` and `phone` fields MongoDB 2.6 will use index intersection. But using compound index is almost always faster than index intersection. More info https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071

Comment: Cool, thanks! In this case, I think, an intersection should take no time, since when I query with an email-address there should be no results in the phone index and vice versa. So it basically is an intersect-with-nothing operation :)